# web api json deserialization failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a request endpoint using in web api:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Create(IList<SlideContent> l)
    {
        ...
    }
```

i send the parameter as a json and web api serializes it to IList

SlideContent is:

```
public abstract class SlideItem
    {
       ...
    }
```

and i have specialised classes

```
    public class TitleSlideItem : SlideItem
    {
        ...
    }


    public class ParagraphSlideItem : SlideItem
    {
       ...
    }
```

just like that i can't call the Create function, because i get a

> missingmethodexception: cannot create abstract class

so i can't deserialize the json parameter. if i remove the abstract modifier, then i don't have specialized objects, every object's type will be `SlideContent`.
I even put annotations in the json, but it doesn't help either.

If i'm not wrong, the i would have to write a custom binder for the abstract class, but how can i do that?

Sincerely,

Zoli

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to substitute the built-in JSON serializer with a custom formatter using JSON.NET as shown in the [following blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx).

```
public class JsonNetFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    private JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSerializerSettings;

    public JsonNetFormatter(JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings)
    {
        _jsonSerializerSettings = jsonSerializerSettings ?? new JsonSerializerSettings();

        // Fill out the mediatype and encoding we support
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(IKeyValueModel))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    protected override Task<object> OnReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream stream, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders, FormatterContext formatterContext)
    {
        // Create a serializer
        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_jsonSerializerSettings);

        // Create task reading the content
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding))
            {
                using (JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
                {
                    return serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, type);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected override Task OnWriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream, HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders, FormatterContext formatterContext, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        // Create a serializer
        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(_jsonSerializerSettings);

        // Create task writing the serialized content
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding)) { CloseOutput = false })
            {
                serializer.Serialize(jsonTextWriter, value);
                jsonTextWriter.Flush();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

then in `Application_Start` when registering the formatter you could configure the serializer to use type information in the JSON:

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
formatters.Remove(formatters.XmlFormatter);
formatters.Remove(formatters.JsonFormatter);

var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
serializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter());
formatters.Add(new JsonNetFormatter(serializerSettings));
```

and then you could POST the following JSON:

```
[
    { 
        "$type":"AppName.Models.TitleSlideItem, AppName",
        "Id":1,
        "Title":"some title" // this is a specific property of the TitleSlideItemclass
    },
    {
        "$type":"AppName.Models.ParagraphSlideItem, AppName",
        "Id":2,
        "Paragraph":"some paragraph" // this is a specific property of the ParagraphSlideItem class
    }
]
```

which will be successfully deserialized inside this action:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(IList<SlideItem> l)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JsonFx creates custom binders. For example take a look at:

https://code.google.com/p/jsonfx/source/browse/trunk/JsonFx/JsonFx.MvcTemplate/Global.asax.cs

Look at the RegisterBinders() function in that file and the source to the binders or just install JsonFx and create a project using their MVC template and see how they do it or just use their library if that would work for you. That's what I would do.